# Why would SAS assign the value of Medium to the 5th observation when it should assign the value High based on my if then else?

Tags: sas

I'm currently in a SAS course and trying to wrap my head around why SAS is assigning the value of 'Medium' to the 5th observation Burt. I understand what needs to be done to fix the mistake, but I am more interested in WHY SAS is assigning 'Medium' to Burt.

1. Does it have something to do with the or condition?

2. Does it have something to do with the automatic conversion of Character to Numeric?

```
    /* Here is the input data */

    data work.levels;  
       infile datalines missover;
       input Name $ Level $;  
    datalines;
    Frank 1
    Joan 2
    Sui 2
    Jose 3
    Burt 4
    Kelly
    Juan 1
    ;

    /* Here is the DATA step with the incorrect logic */

    data work.expertise;
       set work.levels;
       if level = . then 
          expertise = 'Unknown';
       else if level = 1 then 
          expertise = 'Low';
       else if level = 2 or 3 then
          expertise = 'Medium';
       else 
          expertise = 'High';
     run;

    /* Print Step */
    proc print data=work.expertise;
    run;
```

So like I said I understand that the logic should be

```
    else if level = 2 or level = 3 then
        expertise = 'Medium';
```

But what is causing the "bad" logic to produce a value of 'Medium' for Burt, who has a level of 4? How is SAS reading the bad logic to come up with that value for Burt? Thank in advanced.

Comment: You can also use IN, `if level in (2:3) then...`. 2:3 will tell SAS to check for integers 2, 3 or you could list them out. IN does the OR comparison automatically for either character or numeric comparisons.

Comment: Your understanding of the construct `else if level = 2 or 3 then` in SAS is incorrect.  Nikolay correctly indicates the fully qualified expression based on SAS order of evaluation.  However, your stated understanding is correct in the context of a `COBOL` program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if level = 2 or 3` is probably interpreted as `if (level = 2) or (3)`, which is always true, because the value `3` is non-zero and is not a missing value.

From the [`IF-THEN/ELSE` documentation](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0202239.htm):

> SAS evaluates the expression in an IF-THEN statement to produce a result that is either nonzero, zero, or missing. A nonzero and nonmissing result causes the expression to be true; a result of zero or missing causes the expression to be false.`

I assume similar rules are used when evaluating logical operators.

Comment: How would that explain why when level = 4 it would still return 'Medium'? Something seems to be happening where SAS is ignoring the ELSE statement at the bottom, which is where level = 4 should return 'HIGH'.

Comment: As Nickolay explained, your third condition will always be TRUE, so SAS never needs to get to the `else then` part. That's just the way if-then-else works, not just for SAS, but for every langugae.

Comment: @DominicComtois Ahh that makes complete sense. So SAS never gets a chance to continue to the 4th condition because the third will always return a value if it reaches that point. Makes 100% sense, just needed to someone to help me take off my blinders. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, glad to help :)